# Excel - function to convert first letter of each word to uppercase

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am searching for the formula that converts first letter of each word to uppercase(and nothing more). Any idea how to do this?
for example: 
"my WAA task" should be converted to "My WAA Task" 
I found PROPER function, but it also converts all others letters to lower case(so it gives me "My Waa Task") but I don't need this

Comment: You'll need Excel 2016 with an Office 365 subscription if you want to do this using worksheet formulas alone. Do you have that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods,

Formula, only works with Office 365 or higher:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),1)) & MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),2,99))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of enter.

[image]

---

UDF, can be used with older versions.

```
Function fLetter(str As String) As String
    Dim strarr() As String
    strarr = Split(str)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(strarr) To UBound(strarr)
        strarr(i) = UCase$(Left$(strarr(i), 1)) & Mid$(strarr(i), 2)
    Next i
    fLetter = Join(strarr, " ")
End Function
```

then call:

```
=fLetter(A1)
```

[image]